# アップロードした画像の表示の仕方 / [ error ] class MultipartFormData takes type parameters

Tags: scala, playframework

アップロードした画像をブラウザに表示したいので、(sihouetteのrequest.identityのように、)MultipartFormDataをviewに渡せば良いのではないかと思ったのですが、うまくいきません。

```
>class MultipartFormData takes type parameters
```

問題が起きているのはviewの最初の引数の宣言の部分です。

> @(user: models.User, picName: MultipartFormData, fileOption: Option[Long])(implicit request: RequestHeader, messages: Messages, webJarAssets: WebJarAssets)

MultipartFormDataの型パラメータがどれに当たるのか、わかりません。そもそもMultipartFormDataを渡すべきなのかもわかりません。

(FileUploadController.scala)

```
  type FilePartHandler[A] = FileInfo => Accumulator[ByteString, FilePart[A]]

  def handleFilePartAsFile: FilePartHandler[File] = {
    case FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>
      val attr = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(util.EnumSet.of(OWNER_READ, OWNER_WRITE))
      val path: Path = Files.createTempFile("multipartBody", "tempFile", attr)

      if (Files.notExists(path)) Files.createFile(path)

      val file = path.toFile

      val fileSink: Sink[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.toPath(path)
      val accumulator: Accumulator[ByteString, IOResult] = Accumulator(fileSink)
      accumulator.map {
        case IOResult(count, status) =>
          logger.info(s"count = $count, status = $status")
          FilePart(partName, filename, contentType, file)
      }
  }

  def upload = silhouette.SecuredAction.async(parse.multipartFormData(handleFilePartAsFile)) { implicit request =>

    val fileOption = request.body.file("picName").map {

      case FilePart(key, filename, contentType, file) =>
        logger.info(s"key = ${key}, filename = ${filename}, contentType = ${contentType}, file = $file")

        val data = operateOnTempFile(file)

    FileUploadFormSupport.picsave(key, filename, contentType, file)

        data

    }

    Future.successful(Ok(views.html.fileUpload2(request.identity, request.body.file("picName"), fileOption)))
    }
}
```

(fileupload2.scala.html)

```
@(user: models.User, picName: MultipartFormData, fileOption: Option[Long])(implicit request: RequestHeader, messages: Messages, webJarAssets: WebJarAssets)

@import b3.inline.fieldConstructor

@main(Messages("fileupload.title"), Some(user)) {

   <div class="user col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="row data">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">

                <img src="file">
                    <p class="col-md-6"><strong>@Messages("file.name"):</strong></p>
                    <p class="col-md-6">file size is @fileOption.getOrElse("None")</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Comment: english https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740969/how-to-display-an-image-file-in-view-error-class-multipartformdata-takes-typ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。

@(file: Option[MultipartFormData.FilePart[java.io.File]])

以上のように記すことでエラーが消えました。